# How to find out address in binary file with python code only?

Tags: python, binary, offset

I have binary  for example https://github.com/andrew-d/static-binaries/blob/master/binaries/linux/x86_64/nmap

1) How to find what is the address of this series of bytes :`48 8B 45 A8 48 8D 1C 02 48 8B 45 C8` ? , the result need to be `0x6B0C67`

2)How to find out the 12 bytes that in address `0x6B0C67` ? the result need to be `48 8B 45 A8 48 8D 1C 02 48 8B 45 C8` .

3) How to find which address call to specific string? for example `i + 1 == features[i].index` that locate in `0x6FC272` ?  the result need to be `0x4022F6`

How can I find all of this without open Ida? only with python/c code?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For 1) Is your file small enough to be loaded into memory? Then it's as simple as

```
offset = open(file, 'rb').read().find(
    bytes.fromhex("48 8B 45 A8 48 8D 1C 02 48 8B 45 C8")
)

# offset will be -1 if not found
```

If not, you will need to read it in chunks.

For 2), do

```
with open(file, 'rb') as stream:
   stream.seek(0x6b0c67)
   data = stream.read(12)
```

I'm afraid I don't understand the question in 3)...

Comment: The question seems to be asking about a linux executable file, which should definitely be small enough to be loaded into memory.

Comment: @ChristophBurschka  1+2 not work, you guese that binary starting  from offset 0x0,, that not correct, Ida load it from another offset ,

Comment: Could you expand on what lda does and what is the relationship between file offsets and "addresses"? It sounds like you need some more advanced disassembly tools beyond just reading the raw bytes of the file?